# Maintaining Box refresh / access tokens in a disrtibuted system

Tags: box-api

We have multiple servers that access Box, so we turn off auto-refresh.

```
connect.setMaxRequestAttempts(1);
connect.setAutoRefresh(false);
```

Assumptions gathered from unit tests:

- Previous access tokens < 1hr old can still be used for access
- A token
  pair can be refreshed multiple times, as long as a newer token pair
  has not been used for access.

Given that, it appears you can have multiple readers with one writer updating the token pair, even if a reader gets the previous token pair, it should be fine (for access).

We ensure that only one thread in the system updates the tokens, but yet are having issues with 401 errors in spite of locking down the token updates. It seems there something wrong with the assumptions above.

Comment: One odd thing we've recorded is that the token refresh will be delayed if at the same time we are performing a fetch on the file info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are close. Here is the expected behavior:

- A token is valid for one hour, unless a new token is requested and
  used.
- If a new token is requested but not used, the old token is
  still valid (assuming it less than one hour old).
- If a new token is requested and used, the old token is
  invalidated.

Comment: In our tests, we test whether an old token (meaning a newer token has been created AND used) for access still works... It does... So it sounds like in that case Box hasn't had time to essentially invalidate it, maybe cached or what-not. I'll see if trying the old token after a longer period fails.

Comment: So waiting a minute gives it enough time for the old tokens to fail properly. It would seem there is no guarantee other than to serialize _all_ access to Box then.

Comment: @Joel you're correct that the old token will continue to work for a short period of time, even after the new token is used. This was intentional to help in scenarios where a client might have an in-flight or pending request that uses the old token.